# Add a column of ranks

Tags: r, ranking

I have some data:

```
test <- data.frame(A=c("aaabbb",
"aaaabb",
"aaaabb",
"aaaaab",
"bbbaaa")
)
```

and so on.  All the elements are the same length, and are already sorted before I get them.

I need to make a new column of ranks, "First", "Second", "Third", anything after that can be left blank, and it needs to account for ties.  So in the above case, I'd like to get the following output:

```
   A       B
 aaabbb  First
 aaaabb  Second
 aaaabb  Second
 aaaaab  Third
 bbbaaa
 bbbbaa
```

I looked at rank() and some other posts that used it, but I wasn't able to get it to do what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
test$B <- match(test$A , unique(test$A)[1:3] )
test
       A  B
1 aaabbb  1
2 aaaabb  2
3 aaaabb  2
4 aaaaab  3
5 bbbaaa NA
6 bbbbaa NA
```

One of many ways to do this. Possibly not the *best*, but one that readily springs to mind and is fairly intuitive. You can use `unique` because you receive the data pre-sorted.

As data is sorted another suitable function worth considering is `rle`, although it's slightly more obtuse in this example:

```
rnk <- rle(as.integer(df$A))$lengths
rnk
# [1] 1 2 1 1 1
test$B <- c( rep( 1:3 , times = rnk[1:3] ) , rep(NA, sum( rnk[-c(1:3)] ) ) )
```

`rle` computes the lengths (and values which we don't really care about here) of runs of equal values in a vector - so again this works because your data are already sorted.

And if you don't *have* to have blanks after the third ranked item it's even simpler (and more readable):

```
test$B <- rep(1:length(rnk),times=rnk)
```

Comment: @thelatemail lol, cheers. I guess so. I was also thinking about `rle` as the data is sorted. Seems appropriate so i'll add it as an alternative.

Comment: @SimonO101, see below about the possibility of discontinuous repeats.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a good application for factors:

```
test$B <- as.numeric(factor(test$A, levels = unique(test$A)))
```

`cumsum` also comes to mind, where we add `1` every time the value changes:

```
test$B <- cumsum(c(TRUE, tail(test$A, -1) != head(test$A, -1)))
```

(Like @Simon said, there are many ways to do this...)

Comment: That's useful too, especially if everything needed to be ranked.  In this particular case, it was just the top 3.  Thanks.  Sometimes I think it's great that there are so many ways to do things, and sometimes it makes me want to light my hair on fire.

Comment: @flodel.  Just tested your first answer (using factors) on some of my data, and realized that it doesn't function correctly in all cases.  This is because that it is possible for say, test$A[10] to **look** as if it was equal to test$A[6], with the intermediate elements being different.  Treating them as factors forces equality where it may not be, in this case.

Comment: @pak: it would have been nice to make that clear in your question (the possibility of discontinuous repeats.) That being said, doesn't Simon's answer exhibit the same behavior? Then the `cumsum` might be what you were after.

Comment: @flodel: I didn't realize it was a possibility until I encountered it.  And you're correct, Simon's version does exhibit the same behavior, so the `cumsum` version is what I needed.

Comment: @pak if discontinuous repeats are not counted the same then surely `rle` is what you are after